# Unusual tags keep appearing at the bottom of html document

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

Why does the following html appear within my body tag at the very bottom on every project I have?  However, when I use an incognito browser, these tags disappear.  I do develop in React.js sometimes, but even in projects where I'm not using React, these tags show up.

These tags also appear on every single webpage on the internet I visit.

I have tried erasing all cookies, caches, etc from my browser, but I still get these tags.

```
<div id="lo-engage-ext-container">
    <div data-reactroot></div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/css/content.css">
```

Comment: It's because you have a chrome plugin enabled. Go to Chrome -> Settings -> Extension and disable the extension

Comment: check the chrome extension, i think it added something, you need to remove that extension or disabled that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a chrome extension that you have installed that is appending HTML/CSS Reference to the bottom of the `<body>` tag.

The reason why it works in incognito is because chrome disables extensions while private browsing.

Try to disable your extensions one by one and refreshing the page to see which extension was the culprit.